# :before with an image and content:" " place the content in the bottom right corner

Tags: html, css, reddit

I have a pseudo class :before with a background image 300x200px and the css content:" " is the name of the background and should be positioned in the bottom right corner

I used

```
text-align:right;
```

and used padding the bring the text down but that blows up the height of the element so I need an other solution for this. And no, I can't use a separate element for the text.

Edit: I can't show the code because it's for a subreddit stylesheet and there is much more css then that what I could show

```
#header [name='uh']~a:before, body>.side:before {
position: absolute;

width: 298px;
content: '';
text-align: right;
padding-top: 375px;
padding-right: 2px;
color: rgba(64, 92, 120, 0.7);
top: -207px;
right: -300px;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}

body>.side:before {
top: 70px;
z-index: 100;
top:-200px;
right:0;
}
#header [name='uh'][value$='0'] ~ a:before { background-image: url(%%1%%); content: '/u/Hisfantor';}
```

Comment: Could you provide your code as well, and update your answer. It is quite hard to follow, and it is not clear at all. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Hisfantor. It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve. If you provide the code, we might be able to identify the problem.

Comment: I can't show the code because it's for a subreddit stylesheet and there is much more css then that what I could show

Comment: Include the minimal amount of that code needed to reproduce the current layout. You don't have to (and shot not!) post the whole project. See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the line-height property

See the snippet below, with the CSS and then HTML.

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.test::before {
  content: "image";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 600px;
  background-image: url("https://hub.91mobiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Google-Now-launcher.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/kk0bjw5e/6/)

I hope this helps..

Comment: that might work, thank you for the idea